# Should I teach my interns and Junior Employees?

Tags: internship, junior

I am a self taught Software Developer. According to my job description I have to mentor and teach my Interns and Juniors everything I know in Software Development.

There is no problem in mentoring or Teaching them, the problem is that they learn from me and joins competitor companies for far more salary then me. The longest any employee stayed back was 2 years. When I ask why you want to leave this company and goto the other company, the reason I get is '*Their offer is better*'.

Should I teach my interns and Junior Employees?

Comment: If your employer is underpaying junior staff they'll all leave after a year or two regardless of what level of training you provide.

Comment: Since it's in your job description, the answer seems to be an obvious Yes. Is that what you are really asking? Is there a reason the juniors should not leave if they can get a better salary?

Comment: Why haven't you left for a competitor who'll pay a better salary?

Comment: I think the main points of the answers you are receiving are : 1 -> do your job. If your job includes teaching them, do so. 2-> If you feel undervalued, and you are discouraged by the fact of having teach the same things over and over again, that's a separate problem. Discuss with your bosses/ start looking elsewhere. but DO NOT blame the juniors that leave for your own issues in the company. And if they are badmouthing you in their new company, you may want to reconsider how you teach/behave with them (especially when they announce that they quit).

Answer (score 8):

1. Your job description requires you to teach them - so teach them, regardless of the outcome. Your managers are probably aware of the fact that juniors leave the company, it's their job to worry about that, not yours. Do what you've been paid to do. You will do far more damage to your own company by ignoring those you're required to teach, so that they will stay, than you will by teaching them and having them leave.
2. You are worried about the juniors leaving and getting paid more than you. If pay is a concern, maybe you should look at applying to the same places the people you teach end up (if they can make it, the person who teaches them should have a reasonable opportunity). Alternatively, do research as to how much you should be getting paid and bring this to your manager, explaining the situation, and ask for a raise.

One option you do have immediately. Talk to your superiors, find out why they promote teaching like this. If you are able to see the same value of it that your superiors see, you'll have a much better experience actually performing the role. It's good that everyone, Managers, Teachers and Students are on the same page.

Comment: So you mean to say that they should use me as a Ladder and later throw me when they reach there destination. Sounds stupid!

Comment: @RedVirus That's an extremely pessimistic view of what teaching is. Maybe if that's your mindset, you should talk to your superiors about your concerns and see if someone else could take over your teaching role. As it stands, they obviously believe in teaching and should probably know your feelings about it. Maybe they'll actually clarify the goal of your role, which could help focus you and make you feel better about your job.

Comment: Thanks am going to talk to my boss. I am currently the only senior person in my team. The others has resigned to join other companies. We were 3 of us last week and after 2 weeks I ll be the only one working in the team. Another set of juniors will come and then again to teach them and they will leave too. I think this is my life, they only pay me 23k.

Comment: If you think you're underpaid, find a better job yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Teach them on the job, whatever they need to know to do it competently. You're not supposed to start classrooms and delve into theory with them.

What they do with the knowledge is not your business. They have as much right to advance in their careers as anyone else. It sounds like your workplace is a stepping stone. This can work to your advantage.

Guys I trained when they were first starting still call me 'The Guru' and 15 years later I get a lot of respect and work through them, some have risen to very high govt and private sector positions. If this industry is your career, start looking long term not just your situation right now.

Comment: No one calls me 'The Guru' but they do talk bad about me when they join the new company. I' am the only Senior Developer in this company. 3 Hours a day is taken out in teaching them and fixing their code over and over again.

Comment: Doesn't look like teaching is your forte